# Current possibilities for tracing program flow in C#?

Tags: c#, debugging, trace, program-flow

I have used [Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) a few years ago to **trace program flow** during execution **without needing to manually add trace statements** to the methods.

Is there any other new ways to trace execution to to debug output in a similar way?

(Preferably a way that doesn't need to instrument the built assemblies. Maybe not possible?)

Comment: From what I understand, [aspect-orientated programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) in C# _always_ requires post-processing of your compiled code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want this ability at debug time, there's Microsoft [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) that's a part of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and there's Sergey Vlasov's [RunTime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html). The former makes your program run very slow. Haven't tried the latter.

Comment: I use the ultimate edition so IntelliTrace is definitely interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Intellitrace feels a little difficult to navigate but fits perfectly since it's available on all developer computers here. Great!
Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

[Gibraltar](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/See/) uses PostSharp, but provides you with a very powerful client for visualizing your program flow. You can also compare snapshots, view statistics, etc.. Unfortunately it's not free :)

Moreover, most dependency injection frameworks (Unity, Windsor, Ninject, ...) provide method interception. In most cases, you can define traced methods within the app.config file. However, I prefer PostSharp :)

Comment: Do you have any experience in how much overhead Gibraltar adds to instrumented programs?

Comment: No :\ But due to the fact, that PostSharp transforms the assemblies, there should be a minimum of overhead. I guess they use a Tcp/UdpClient in an async manner for data transfer.

Comment: The Gibraltar concept seems very interesting. I'll make sure we'll try it for some fitting project in the near future. Thank you! :)

Comment: Gibraltar is designed for use in production - we have guidance on how to inject a lot of information without dragging down your application.  Give us a try and we're happy to work with you to find the sweet spot for your situation!