# visual studio check which classes and or methods have been called

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Im currently working on a project which has a lot of work already done on it. The problem is that I am looking for UI classes that have been tucked away nicely somewhere in another framework. Its possible to determine which class has thrown an error in the other framework using debugging and a reference path to it but i am not sure if i can when it doesn't.

I've had a good Google of the question but for some reason it only provides links to testing practices.

The underlying question here:

**is it possible to determine the name and location of the last called class and or method in Visual Studio?**

*example*

If mainPage.cs page executes then this could output as

> mainPage.cs
>
> C:\SourceCode\mainPage.cs

For reference here are a few Google Searches I used to try and ascertain an answer before resorting to SO:

> visual studio check which classes are currently running
>
> visual studio check which classes have been called
>
> which class is currently running in visual studio

Are there possibly even any classes in C# that can determine the last called class/method

Comment: Check out Intellitrace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx

Comment: @This looks interesting. Can I run this in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: No, Visual Studio 2012 and up. But it can collect data from a Visual Studio 2008 solution or executable and analyze it in a later version.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614157/current-possibilities-for-tracing-program-flow-in-c

Comment: @sergey Vlasov  great piece of software.