# How to see what methods are being called while debugging app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

Is there a way for me to see what c# methods are being called when debugging a xaml based app in visual studio? For example, when I click a button is there a way for me to see what method was called?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614157/current-possibilities-for-tracing-program-flow-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Look for the "Call Stack" window. It seems to be exactly what you are looking for.
Another possibility is to use debug outputs or breakpoints.