# Logging the flow of control in Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I am working with Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, on an extremely large code base.

I am currently trying to debug an issue, but i am unable to place breakpoints correctly, and relying on pure guesswork and hit-n-trial.

Is there any way by which we can **list the entire trace of flow of control** in VS 2013? 
(The entry and exit of the functions which are called)

```
(PS: There are no explicit logging statements written in the code).
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614157/current-possibilities-for-tracing-program-flow-in-c

Comment: Thanks, but is there anything for C++ as well? The above solution is supported only for the following:
ASP.NET, Microsoft Azure, Windows Forms, WCF, WPF, Windows Workflow, SharePoint 2010, SharePoint 2013, and 64-bit apps.

Comment: The above solution should work for any .NET application. If your project is native C++ then I don't know an alternative.