# It is possible to show full execution of program automatically in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to show the full execution of my c# program/project automatically and slowly in visual studio C#.

I know we can do it using debugging point, but it's a manual process, but what to do to make it automatic and want to know that how and where the execution is going.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614157/current-possibilities-for-tracing-program-flow-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like [IntelliTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx), however it's only for Enterprise and above editions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know " Navigating through Code with the Debugger"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Also i recommended  you tool use some third party add on in Visual studio

**IntelliTrace**  is good one

i recommended you to follow

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/11/01/debugging-tools-for-the-net-developer.aspx