# There are methods to tracking call's in MVC .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, logging

I m working  with a large project whith meets in mvc c# and looking for methods (plugins for visual studio, addons, frameworks) for tracking object in controller,views during the app works. Any methods exist for that ? I do not want use logging via nlog or log4net.

Comment: Not clear on exactly what you are looking for, but [Stackify Prefix](http://stackify.com/prefix) gives you a lot of profiling data without instrumenting your code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614157/current-possibilities-for-tracing-program-flow-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Try Application Insights (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview). It integrated very nice in Visual Studio, has a free plan as well and is created for scenario's like this.

Just to satisfy my curiosity, why do you not want to use a logging framework?