# VS Debug: Show callstack and parameters of methods (while debugging) without stepping into?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I was wondering is there a way to check what methods were recently called, and the parameters of them are? I seem to find myself having a lot of everyones in methods, but it only tells me the line that it happened on, I use nlog to log my exceptions, and then I go to the client and file it was logged on, but I constantly find myself having to Console.WriteLine() before every method to know what parameters were passed.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614157/current-possibilities-for-tracing-program-flow-in-c